# how to disable server side validation on asp.net web forms from browser?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I wanted to disable asp.net validation server controls from browser. I checked online but did not find any way to disable the server side validation; it can be disabled only on the client side using JS/jQuery.

Here is the scenario: I have a checkbox and selecting which displays a set of text boxes. Only if the checkbox is checked, required field validator should fire for the text boxes. I don't want to call a postback on checkbox. Actually those chceck boxes will be generated with jQuery templating so postback is not an option to enable disable validtion.

I would like to know whether there is any way we can enable disable the .CausesValidation property for the controls from browser using some setting? Or is there a way to capture the controls which are to be considered for validation slectively in some event before page_load?

[Update]
Based on Accepted answer, here is my solution:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req1" ControlToValidate="textbox1" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="enter text"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req2" ControlToValidate="textbox2" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="enter text for 2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server" Text="choose" />
    <asp:Button ID="submitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="submitBtn_Click" Text="submit" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvBox" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error" ValidationGroup="prueba"
        OnServerValidate="Validarcaja"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="summary" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    req1.Enabled = false;
    req2.Enabled = false;
}
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Response.Write("valid form");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("invalid form");
        }
    }
}
protected void Validarcaja(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (check1.Checked)
    {
        req1.Enabled = true;
        req1.Validate();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me would be to use a CustomValidator with a OnServerValidate method.

In the OnServerValidate method I would check if the checkbox is checked, in that case I would verify if the textboxes are filled. It is not necessary to do any change in the CausesValidation property.
The only condition is not to include the property "ControlToValidate". A CustomValidator does not fire if the textbox is empty that's why.
So the code would be like this:

```
  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" ValidationGroup="prueba" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chb" runat="server" Text="Check" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvBox" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="Error" ValidationGroup="prueba"  
    OnServerValidate="Validarcaja"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Prueba" />
```

And the codebehind:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
 if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Page.Validate();
            }
            }

            protected void Validarcaja(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
            {
                if (chb.Checked)
                {
                    if (txbBox.Text == String.Empty)
                    {
                        cvBox.IsValid = false;                    
                    }

                }
            }
```